# Building umdl/pmdl after Snowboy closing

Tags: snowboy

As KITT.AI announced in March they are closing all operations and support (leaving GitHub repository) at the end of the year.

So my question is how can we build custom keywords afrerwards? Is build tool included in public code on GitHub?

training_service.py just calls Kitt.Ai server, that will be shutdown on 31th in December

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [forked GitHub repo](https://github.com/seasalt-ai/snowboy) where you can find updated instructions for offline training of custom pmdl model:

`python generate_pmdl.py -r1=record1.wav -r2=record2.wav -r3=record3.wav -lang=en -n=hotword.pmdl`

This script can be found in `examples/Python` directory.

It also seems that script can be modified to provide more than 3 recordings.